# Laptop projecting to second screen gets extremely hot

Tags: laptop, hdmi, cooling, external-display

I have an ultrabook which gets extremely hot when projecting to a second screen via the HDMI port.  I'm not doing anything I wouldn't normally use the laptop for, so it's specifically when it's dealing with the second monitor.

Is there anything I can do to keep my laptop from cooking outside of avoiding plugging it into my monitor?

Comment: **[GPU-z](http://www.techpowerup.com/gpuz/)** will let you easily see how stressed your GPU is. If it has a fan then it will show you the fan speed as well. Since it is an ultrabook I would imagine that it's possible there is no fan at all. What ultrabook model do you have?

Comment: @MonkeyZeus, this is a Samsung Series 9 from 2 years ago.  NP900X4C is the exact model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could be drawing too much power through your GPU. Try lowering the resolution of the monitor.

If that doesn't work, the next step would probably be to isolate where the problem is occurring. Try experimenting with a few different monitors.

If the problem persists with different monitors, your computer is doing something funky. If it doesn't, the driver for the monitor could be doing something funky or the monitor itself might be the issue.

[Here](http://www.tomshardware.com/forum/364722-33-multiple-monitors-overheating) is a link to a similar question on a different site.

Also, is your fan running or is it shutting off? Because [this](http://en.community.dell.com/owners-club/alienware/f/3746/p/19437680/20078616) person's GPU fan was turning off.

Comment: My fans have normally been extremely quiet.  Is there any utility out there that you know of which would let me see if they're spinning?

Comment: What brand computer?

Comment: @MushinNoShin just tagging you to notify you

Comment: this is a Samsung Series 9 from about 2 years ago.  I opened it up and only saw a single fan (even with multiple vents).  The casing is aluminum, so I think it's intentional that the case itself helps dissipate the heat.  I've been leaving it open with the screen turned on when plugged in, and that's helped a lot with the heat.

Comment: I tried [this](https://search.yahoo.com/yhs/search?p=Samsung+fan+monitor&ei=UTF-8&hspart=mozilla&hsimp=yhs-002) search and the very last result seems to be what you are looking for, but I hesitate to recommend it as I know absolutely nothing about the software. I would do further research if I were you.

Answer (score 2):

***Explanation :***

When you use your HDMI Port your graphic card is solicitation much more than normal if the laptop is not cooling properly it could result in extreme overheat.

***Solution :***

You need to open your laptop to clean it from dirt and replace it's cooling pate.